# Elastic Beanstalk npm failing

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, npm-install

I am trying to upload my app to Elastic Beanstalk but the npm install is failing on node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build. I have tried various versions of node with no avail. It seems to be trying to get a package for linux which doesn't exist and is not needed, it is only needed for OSX (in which it is working fine).

The solution seems to be to run npm install with the --no-optional flag but I can't find a way to make EB run install with this flag.

Also this package seems to be a dependency for karma, which I only have as a dev dependency in my package.json file. I can see EB is installing using the --production flag so I don't know what it's trying to install it in the first place.

Any ideas on how to work around this issue would be much appreciated.

```
>     Running npm with --production flag
>       Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
>           main()
>         File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
>           node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
>         File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
>           self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
>         File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
>           raise e
>       subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.6.1-linux-x64/bin/npm',
> '--production', 'rebuild']' returned non-zero exit status 1
> (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
>     caused by: + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
>       npm WARN package.json Room@1.0.0 No repository field.
>       npm WARN package.json Room@1.0.0 No README data
>       npm WARN package.json Room@1.0.0 No license field.
>       
>       > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.2.1 postinstall /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
>       > node lib/post_install.js
>       
>       
>       > fsevents@1.0.15 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
>       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>       
>       node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.15/fse-v1.0.15-node-v46-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this, my problem was in my .gitignore I had `node_modules` rather than `node_modules/` and the folder was getting tracked and deployed. Removing the node_modules folder from the deployment solved the issue.

Answer (score 16):

I got similar kind of error as fallows
[image]

When I looked at more details section I found this ,where it  was an error in the `bcrypt` library 
[image]

So I removed that library and installed [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)   library and deployed it again ,then it was successful deployed. So this kind of errors may appear when there are deprecated libraries and not supportive libraries .

Comment: I ran into the same problem this morning. Uninstalling bcrypt and installing ``` bcrypt-nodejs``` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

First, check your log by going to

1. Go to `Elastic Beanstalk.`
2. Click on your app's environment name
3. Select `Logs` on the sidebar
4. Click on `Request Logs` and select `Last 100 Lines` or `Full Log.`
5. From your log, you will see why npm is failing

Time to fix it!

6. if it is related to `gyp WARN`, `gyp WARN EACCESS` or `gyp ERR`, then create a file called .npmrc in the root directory of your project. In this file, add `unsafe-perm=true`. This will force npm to run node-gyp as root.
7. if the error is related to a particular npm package failing to install, kindly consider an alternative to that package.

All the best !!

Comment: The step 6) did it for me. I was trying to run puppeteer on a EB/EC2 environment. For some reason, puppeteer wouldn't install without the `.npmrc` file with the command line `unsafe-perm=true`. Tho i'm unsure about what could that impact (Apparently you're installing packages as a root user?).

Comment: Nice this is like having a formula